# Navigating across navigator in react navigation using typescript

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have an expo app with react navigation. The navigation flow is like

```
 NavigationContainer
      AuthNavigator (Bottom tab navigator)
         SigninStack (Stack navigator)
           SigninScreen
           OtpScreen
           ResetPasswordScreen
           ForgotPasswordScreen
         SignupStack (Stack navigator)
           SignupScreen
           BioScreen
           OtpScreen 
      HomeNavigator (Bottom tab navigator)
         HomeStack (Stack navigator)
           HomeScreen
           ItemScreen
         ProfileStack (Stack navigator)
           ViewProfileScreen
           EditProfileScreen
```

Now I want to navigate from SigninScreen under SigninStack(Stack navigator) under AuthNavigator(Bottom tab navigator) to HomeScreen under HomeStack(Stack navigator) under HomeNavigator(Bottom tab navigator). For acheiving this, in the SigninScreen, I am doing something like

```
navigation.navigate("HomeStack", {
    screen: "HomeScreen",
});
```

This is throwing error like

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeStack","params":{"screen":"HomeScreen"}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'HomeStack'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

[This](https://github.com/sandheep45/dinedrop-expo) is the github repo for reference purpose

Any kind of very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to navigate from    `SignInStack` to `HomeStack` which is impossible with a `navigation.navigate("HomeStack")`. This is the normal behaviour. Those lines in your code are important to understand why:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
// ..
  {!isAuthenticated ? <AuthTab.Navigator /> : <HomeTab.Navigator />}
// ..
</NavigationContainer>
```

This means that:

- If the user `isAuthenticated` you will **NEVER** have access to your `SignInStack`
- If the user is **NOT** `isAuthenticated`, you will **NEVER** have access to your `HomeStack` (and it looks like it’s what you are trying to achieve)

The solution here is to go for a global context manager to handle `isAuthenticated`. This `react-navigation` [tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) may help.

After the singin process, update globally the `isAuthenticated` variable to `true`, navigation will be handled automatically.

Comment: Does this means we can't navigate from one navigator to another ever?

Comment: This means that the only way to navigate from one to another, is to update the global variable `isAuthenticate`